# AFNetworking include headers

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to convert from ASIHttpRequest to AFNetworking but I seem to be having a "Use of undeclared identifier AFURLSessionManager" error on the following line in my class.

```
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];
```

I have included the following on my header:

```
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "AFURLSessionManager.h"
```

It must be something really obvious, but having a bad brain fart right now.

Comment: how did you import the framework? Are you using CocoaPods?

Comment: I actually just dragged the AFNetworking folder into my project, like it had it here http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_afnetworking/

Comment: ...did you download AFNetworking from the repository, or from the link on the tutorial site?

Comment: Something is probably wrong with the linking. Not quite an answer to the issue, but seriously consider switching to CocoaPods. It takes you 5 minutes and it saves you hours of dependencies management.

Comment: I got it from the git hub

Comment: I'm very interested in this question.  I'm using cocoapods in a new application.  No problems with using the new AFHTTPRequestOperationManager, but I have the same error as @RayY when using AFURLSessionManager

Comment: I'm not sure its an error on the copy of AFNetworking on GitHub here: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/ I thought it would be a drop in replacement for ASIHttpRequest but it seems there is some deep configuration that has to be done first.

Comment: @ChamaraPaul Does your project support iOS 6? In this case, AFURLSessionManager isn't automatically installed

Comment: Ah yes @DavidCaunt, my deployment target is set to 6.1...

Comment: I tried to use cocoapods with my app and used the xcworkspace file to open my project, now when I compile I get AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h file not found. Do I need to add Pods to the header search paths or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior is simply explained by this line of code in [`AFURLSessionManager.h`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.h#L83)

```
#if (defined(__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 70000) || (defined(__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED) && __MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 1090)
```

`AFURLSessionManager` makes use of `NSURLSession`, which is available from iOS 7 (and OSX 10.9) on.

If you are targeting iOS 6, `AFURLSessionManager` just can't be used and it's stripped out at compile time. That's why you get the error.

Setting iOS 7 as minimum deployment target will fix the compile error, even though it may not fit your needs.

---

That said, my suggestions is to use CocoaPods to managed third-party dependencies, such as `AFNetworking`.

`AFNetworking 2.0` is a modular framework, meaning that you can pick which modules to use according to your needs. The core supports iOS 6, but some modules only support iOS 7, such as the `NSURLSession` module which is the one where `AFURLSessionManager` belongs.

Modularity is achieved by using [CocoaPods subspecs](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/wiki/The-podspec-format#subspecs). In order to import `AFNetworking` and the `NSURLSession` module, you will just have to do something like

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'AFNetworking',              '~> 2.0'
pod 'AFNetworking/NSURLSession', '~> 2.0'
```

You still can target iOS 6, but you won't get the incompatible submodules, as specified in the CocoaPods documentation.

> A subspec can restrict the platform of the parent specification. In this case it will be inherited by the parent specification only if the target of the podfile supports it.

Comment: Fixed it, I used cocoapods to install AFNetworking then had to add the "${PODS_ROOT}/BuildHeaders" into my Header Search Paths in Build Settings.

Comment: actually if you use cocoapods it produces a workspace automatically configured. Just open the workspace and use it instead of the project.