# Can't use AFHTTPRequestOperationManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, httprequest, afnetworking

I got a problem when I'm using AFNetworking. I wrote this in my code:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
```

I do add those files in my project, and I also try pod them into my project [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaIG0.png). But the compiler still told me "use of undeclared identifier 'AFHTTPRequestOperationManager'". Someone can help me?

screenshot:[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3KNh.png)

Comment: #import "AFNetworking.h" ? :]

Comment: First . If you add AFNetworking through pod. Then there is not need to add manually file of Afnetworking

Comment: Thanks,  I know, but both of them didn't work.

Comment: please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100759/afnetworking-include-headers

Comment: Add #import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h" into .m file

Comment: Hi @HongxuJin if possible please accept the answer which is useful to you so other users are able to identify which one is best to follow.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In fact, it's because after AFNetworking 3.x, there is no AFHTTPRequestOperationManager any more. You should use AFHTTPSessionManager instead.

Answer (score 8):

Please check the profile - AFNetworking version

Change to

> pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5.4'
>
> and use
>
> ## import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"

Answer (score 0):

In Your View controller .h file add

`#import <AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h>`

And then check it

Comment: It said 'AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h' file not found.

Comment: I added the screenshot.

Comment: You remove class AFNetworking & Uikit +  AFNetworking From your project on shown in first two. Only keep in pod

Comment: @MaulikPatel It still doesn't work. you can see it in screenshot2 in my question. And if I add #import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h", it still can't be found.

Comment: Yes I am, you can see the pods in project navigator.

Comment: It's very strange issue..Because  in my all project every time i use AFNetworking & CocoaPod .But can't Face this problem .I just add Header file as i say in answer.Can you Share your basic project?

Comment: Sure, may I send it to your mailbox?

Comment: you have dropbox account?

Comment: if yes then send me in dropbox

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have one. So may I use mailbox?

Comment: @Maulik Patel any solution? i have got same issue