# LinkedIn integration to objective-c iOS, Without installing LinkedIn App

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

Integrate LinkedIn application into my iOS (Objective-c) project it is working good when LinkedIn is installed otherwise its showing one alert install LinkedIn app But now I want to handle if LinkedIn app is not installed if any body have idea give me the answer and please check below code for understanding .

```
NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION, LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION, nil];


[LISDKSessionManager createSessionWithAuth:permissions state:nil showGoToAppStoreDialog:YES successBlock:^(NSString *returnState){

            NSLog(@"%s","success called!");

            LISDKSession *session = [[LISDKSessionManager sharedInstance] session];
[[LISDKAPIHelper sharedInstance] getRequest:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,email-address,picture-url)", LINKEDIN_API_URL]

                                                success:^(LISDKAPIResponse *response)
             {


                 NSData* data = [response.data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                 NSDictionary *dictResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

NSString *authUsername = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", [dictResponse valueForKey: @"firstName"], dictResponse];
} error:^(LISDKAPIError *apiError) {

                 NSLog(@"Error  : %@", apiError);

             }];

        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

            NSLog(@"Error called  : %@", error);

        }];
```

Comment: You should be able to use `canOpenURL` with a `linkedin://` url

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** add these two pods in your pod file.

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5.4'
pod 'IOSLinkedInAPI', '~> 2.0'
```

**Step 2:** Import these libraries

```
#import <linkedin-sdk/LISDK.h>
#import <LIALinkedInHttpClient.h>
#import <LIALinkedInApplication.h>
#import <AFHTTPRequestOperation.h>
```

**Step 3:** Make a property in the class where you want linkedIn login:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) LIALinkedInHttpClient *client;
```

**Step 4:** Write this method in the class where you want to use and also give the constant values of your linked app(like clientID and client Secret and redirectURL).

```
- (LIALinkedInHttpClient *)clientSettings {
    LIALinkedInApplication *application = [LIALinkedInApplication     applicationWithRedirectURL:kRedirectURL     clientId:kClientID clientSecret:kClientSecret   state:@"DCEEFWF45453sdffef424342" grantedAccess:@[@"r_basicprofile",@"r_emailaddress"]];

    return [LIALinkedInHttpClient clientForApplication:application         presentingViewController:self.window.rootViewController];
}
```

**Step 5:** Write this line in the class where you want to use in viewDidLoad method.

```
 _client = [self clientSettings];
```

**Step 6:** Write this line in Appdelegate's file's method "openURL".

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    BOOL handled;

    if ([LISDKCallbackHandler shouldHandleUrl:url]) {
        handled = [LISDKCallbackHandler application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
    }
    return handled;
}
```

**Step 7:** Now write these methods in the class where you want to use linked in login.

```
- (void)didTapConnectWithLinkedIn {

    [self.client getAuthorizationCode:^(NSString *code) {

        [self.client getAccessToken:code success:^(NSDictionary *accessTokenData) {
            NSString *accessToken = [accessTokenData objectForKey:@"access_token"];
            [self requestMeWithToken:accessToken];
        }                   failure:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Querying accessToken failed %@", error);
        }];
    }                      cancel:^{
        NSLog(@"Authorization was cancelled by user");
    }                     failure:^(NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Authorization failed %@", error);
    }];
}

- (void)requestMeWithToken:(NSString *)accessToken {

    [self.client GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,email-address,formatted-name,phonetic-last-name,location:(country:(code)),industry,distance,current-status,current-share,network,skills,phone-numbers,date-of-birth,main-address,positions:(title),educations:(school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities))?oauth2_access_token=%@&format=json", accessToken] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSDictionary *result) {


        NSLog(@"current user %@", result);


    }        failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"failed to fetch current user %@", error);
    }];

}
```

**Step 8:** Now call only the method "didTapConnectWithLinkedIn" on your IBAction button.

**Thats it. Happy coding. (if any problem comes please ask me in commits).**

Comment: Hi Thank you for your responding, I just try as you but I get AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h' file not found errors bcecause im using updated AFNetworking pod file so im getting this error.

Comment: Yes it is. can't you use old version? any issue using 2.5.4 in other your code files?

Comment: Yes, im already develop hole project with latest AFNetworking so now i can't modified total code, There is any other options to develop. If i'm use 2.5.4 then I get more changes.

Comment: oh then you have to modify LinkedIn SDK with this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893706/cant-use-afhttprequestoperationmanager